# JSON not valid after json_encode posts

Tags: posts, array, content, json, encoding

I'm having problems saving JSON in a custom table in my database. I pull some posts (+ connected posts) from the database and add them to an array.

This is a part of my array:

```
array(2) {
    ["post"]=>
    array(22) {
      ["post_author"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["post_date"]=>
      string(19) "2015-07-30 13:36:23"
      ["post_date_gmt"]=>
      string(19) "2015-07-30 13:36:23"
      ["post_content"]=>
      string(1002) "[:en]Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.[:]"
      ["post_title"]=>
      string(15) "[:en]azezaez[:]"
      ["post_excerpt"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["post_status"]=>
      string(7) "publish"
      ["comment_status"]=>
      string(6) "closed"
      ["ping_status"]=>
      string(4) "open"
      ["post_password"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["post_name"]=>
      string(7) "azezaez"
      ["to_ping"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["pinged"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["post_modified"]=>
      string(19) "2015-07-31 07:55:19"
      ["post_modified_gmt"]=>
      string(19) "2015-07-31 07:55:19"
      ["post_content_filtered"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["post_parent"]=>
      int(0)
      ["guid"]=>
      string(41) "http://vkgroup.dx-solutions.be/en/?p=2053"
      ["menu_order"]=>
      int(0)
      ["post_type"]=>
      string(4) "post"
      ["post_mime_type"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["comment_count"]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
    ["connected_projects"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      object(WP_Post)#751 (28) {
        ["ID"]=>
        int(1965)
        ["post_author"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["post_date"]=>
        string(19) "2015-06-26 14:10:39"
        ["post_date_gmt"]=>
        string(19) "2015-06-26 14:10:39"
        ["post_content"]=>
        string(3754) "[:en]The Brussels Saint Luc's University Hospitals decided to thoroughly renovate six operating rooms over a surface of 800 sqm in the middle of the operating block, situated on level -2 of the hospital. The original rooms date from the opening of the hospital in 1976.

  A competition was organized for the renovation of 6 intervention rooms, annex medical-technical spaces, work and stock spaces, along with the creation of two pre anesthesia and/or transplanting rooms.

  The design consists of a simple, rational and efficient concept. It splits the unit in two zones of three operating rooms each, alongside a large central corridor. The sterile and dirty circulation have been conserved in order to respect the existing internal circulation flows of the hospital.

  Six large rooms of 49 sq. m. each (instead of 30.5 sq. m. previously) have been renovated. At the same time, two pre anesthesia and transplanting areas of 15 sq. m. each were added thanks to a modular wall-system. The large central corridor allows for fluid circulation of personnel. It also leaves room for a bed and wheelchair area without disturbing the operational efficiency of the service, creating a pleasant environment for personnel and patients alike.[:fr]Les Cliniques universitaires Saint-Luc Ã  Bruxelles ont dÃ©cidÃ© la rÃ©novation profonde dâ€™un ensemble de six salles dâ€™opÃ©ration dâ€™une surface de 800 mÂ² en plein cÅ“ur du bloc opÃ©ratoire situÃ© au niveau -2 des Cliniques et Ã  front de lâ€™avenue Hippocrate. Ces salles avaient Ã©tÃ© construites pour lâ€™ouverture des Cliniques en 1976.

  Un concours a Ã©tÃ© organisÃ© portant sur le reconditionnement de 6 salles interventionnelles, des annexes mÃ©dico-techniques, des espaces de travail et de stock avec la crÃ©ation de 2 salles de prÃ©-anesthÃ©sie et/ou de transplantation de greffons.

  Le concept est simple, rationnel et efficace. Il consiste Ã  diviserÂ  lâ€™unitÃ© en deux zones de trois salles dâ€™opÃ©ration desservies par un large couloir central. Les circulations stÃ©riles et sales sont conservÃ©es afin de respecter les circulations internes existantes du service.

  Six grandes salles de 49 mÂ² (au lieu de 30,5 mÂ² prÃ©cÃ©demment) sont rÃ©amÃ©nagÃ©es et deux salles de prÃ©-anesthÃ©sie et de transplantation de greffons de 15 mÂ² chacune sont crÃ©Ã©es grÃ¢ce Ã  lâ€™utilisation du systÃ¨me de paroi de type modulaire. Un large couloir central est Ã©galement amÃ©nagÃ©, permettant une circulation fluide du personnel. Cet amÃ©nagement permet de dÃ©gager une zone dâ€™entreposage de lits et de charriots sans dÃ©ranger le bon fonctionnement du service et gÃ©nÃ¨re un environnement agrÃ©able tant pour les patients que pour le personnel.[:nl]De Cliniques universitaires Saint-Luc in Brussel wilden 6 operatiezalen, een oppervlakte van 800 mÂ² in het hart van het operatiekwartier op niveau -2, grondig renoveren. De zalen dateren van 1976.

  Het concept is eenvoudig, rationeel en efficiÃ«nt. Het geheel wordt opgesplitst in twee zones van elk 3 zalen, doorsneden door een brede centrale gang. De circulatie voor steriele en vuile benodigdheden blijft behouden om de bestaande interne circulatiestromen van het operatiekwartier niet te verstoren.

  Zes grote zalen van 49 mÂ² (in plaats van 30,5 mÂ² voorheen) werden heringericht en twee zalen voor pre-anesthesie en transplantaten, elk 15 mÂ², konden bijgevoegd worden dankzij een modulaire toepassing van scheidingswanden. Er is ook een grote centrale gang ingericht om een vlotte circulatie van het personeel toe te staan.

  Door deze aanpassing kan een zone vrijgemaakt worden voor bedden en rolstoelen zonder de functionaliteit te verstoren, en wordt een aangename omgeving gecreÃ«erd voor de patiÃ«nten en het personeel.[:]"
        ["post_title"]=>
        string(171) "[:en]Saint Luc's University Hospitals, operating block[:fr]Cliniques Universitaires Saint-Luc, bloc opÃ©ratoire[:nl]Cliniques Universitaires Saint-Luc, operatiekwartier[:]"
        ["post_excerpt"]=>
        string(114) "[:en]renovation of 6 operating rooms[:fr]rÃ©novation de 6 salles d'opÃ©ration[:nl]renovatie van 6 operatiezalen[:]"
        ["post_status"]=>
        string(7) "publish"
        ["comment_status"]=>
        string(6) "closed"
        ["ping_status"]=>
        string(6) "closed"
        ["post_password"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["post_name"]=>
        string(34) "cliniques-universitaires-saint-luc"
        ["to_ping"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["pinged"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["post_modified"]=>
        string(19) "2015-07-14 12:55:28"
        ["post_modified_gmt"]=>
        string(19) "2015-07-14 12:55:28"
        ["post_content_filtered"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["post_parent"]=>
        int(0)
        ["guid"]=>
        string(64) "http://vkgroup.dx-solutions.be/en/?post_type=project&p=1965"
        ["menu_order"]=>
        int(0)
        ["post_type"]=>
        string(7) "project"
        ["post_mime_type"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["comment_count"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["filter"]=>
        string(3) "raw"
        ["p2p_id"]=>
        string(4) "1387"
        ["p2p_from"]=>
        string(4) "1965"
        ["p2p_to"]=>
        string(4) "2053"
        ["p2p_type"]=>
        string(15) "project_to_post"
      }
      [1]=>
      object(WP_Post)#749 (28) {
        ["ID"]=>
        int(1777)
        ["post_author"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["post_date"]=>
        string(19) "2015-06-17 20:55:19"
        ["post_date_gmt"]=>
        string(19) "2015-06-17 20:55:19"
        ["post_content"]=>
        string(6918) "[:en]The emergency services of Europe Clinics deal with an increasing influx of patients. Saint Michaelâ€™s campus urgently needed a renovation of the department. The dense urban environment of Etterbeek (Brussels, Belgium) posed some challenges with regard to access to daylight, connection with the surroundings and accessibility for functional flows.

  VKâ€™s design follows the new ESI-triage system (Emergency Severity Index) Europe Clinics is applying. The space is functionally and sequentially divided into urgency zones.

  High-care is immediately situated after triage, and nearest to the elevators that lead to the OR. Low-care and medium-care are situated at the other end of the ER, furthest removed from the reception desk. These patients often have to wait a bit longer for treatment or stay for a day. Hence, this area runs along the outside faÃ§ade, enabling daylight to flow in.

  The medical spaces are furnished as functionally as possible, using stainless steel, synthetic walls, conducted floors and technical ceilings. White is the main tone, with the exception of the colours on the doors: red for high-care, yellow for medium-care and green for low-care. This complies to the personnelâ€™s wishes, indicating to function better in a sober environment, with a minimum of distraction.

  In contrast with this clinical environment, the waiting areas at both ends of the ER are more serene. A waiting area at the reception desk and a waiting area in low-care are furnished with warm colours and pleasant materials. Lighting has been fitted in deep curves with a perforated acoustical ceiling, defining the waiting area. Moreover, the waiting area in low-care also figures a stylized tree. This reference to nature calls forth associations that contribute to a relaxing atmosphere with a sense of security. This piece of fixed furniture also holds a kidâ€™s play corner.

  Evidently, the ER contains all other necessary facilities, including boxes for isolation, interventions, plastering, pediatrics and research. Next to the entrance for acute patients and centrally between all specific zones, lies the personnel room. This area also optimizes the entrance of daylight to the fullest.[:fr]Afin de pouvoir faire face Ã  une augmentation croissante du nombre de patients aux urgences, lesÂ  Cliniques St-Michel (Cliniques de lâ€™Europe) ont dÃ©cidÃ© de reconditionner complÃ¨tement le service. Dans lâ€™environnement urbain trÃ¨s dense dâ€™Etterbeek, la lumiÃ¨re du jour, la connexion avec lâ€™environnement et lâ€™accÃ¨s des flux fonctionnels ont reprÃ©sentÃ© des dÃ©fis de taille.

  La conception de VK prÃ©voit une sÃ©paration claire des patients ambulants et aigus, avec lâ€™application du nouveau systÃ¨me de triage ESI (Emergency Severity Index) et des salles dâ€™attente spacieuses. Lâ€™espace est divisÃ© en zones dâ€™urgences de maniÃ¨re fonctionnelle.

  Le High-care se trouve directement aprÃ¨s le triage et prÃ¨s des ascenseurs qui mÃ¨nent au quartier opÃ©ratoire. Le low-care et le medium-care se situent de lâ€™autre cÃ´tÃ© des urgences, Ã  lâ€™opposÃ© de la rÃ©ception. Ces patients doivent souvent attendre plus longtemps avant dâ€™Ãªtre traitÃ©s. Cette zone est donc proche de la faÃ§ade extÃ©rieure qui bÃ©nÃ©ficie de lumiÃ¨re du jour.

  Ces espaces mÃ©dicaux sont amÃ©nagÃ©s de maniÃ¨re trÃ¨s fonctionnelle, avec de lâ€™acier inoxydable, des murs synthÃ©tiques, des revÃªtements de sol conducteurs et des plafonds techniques. Le ton principal est le blanc, Ã  lâ€™exception des portes qui sont colorÃ©es : rouge pour le high-care, jaune pour le medium-care et vert pour le low-care.

  Pour contraster avec cet environnement clinique, des salles dâ€™attente Ã  lâ€™ambiance plus sereine ont Ã©tÃ© installÃ©es de part et dâ€™autre du service. Une salle dâ€™attente Ã  la rÃ©ception et une salle dâ€™attente dans le low-care ont Ã©tÃ© rÃ©alisÃ©es avec des tons chauds et des matÃ©riaux agrÃ©ables. Lâ€™Ã©clairage est rÃ©alisÃ© avec des courbes prononcÃ©es et des perforations. Un arbre stylisÃ© a Ã©galement Ã©tÃ© installÃ© dans la salle dâ€™attente du low-care. L'image de lâ€™arbre Ã©voque spontanÃ©ment la sÃ©rÃ©nitÃ© et la sÃ©curitÃ© du dÃ©partement. Cet arbre sert aussi dâ€™espace de jeux pour les enfants.

  Les urgences disposent Ã©videmment de tous les Ã©quipements nÃ©cessaires, dont des salles pour lâ€™isolement, la chirurgie, les plÃ¢tres, la pÃ©diatrie, diffÃ©rentes interventions et analyses. Lâ€™espace rÃ©servÃ© au personnel se trouve Ã  cÃ´tÃ© des patients aigus et au centre de toutes les zones spÃ©cifiques. Ces espaces bÃ©nÃ©ficient Ã©galement dâ€™un maximum de lumiÃ¨re du jour.[:nl]De spoedafdelingen van Europaziekenhuizen hebben te maken met een groeiende toestroom van patiÃ«nten. In de site Sint-Michiel drong een renovatie van de spoeddienst zich op. De dichte stedelijke omgeving van Etterbeek zorgde voor de nodige uitdagingen op het vlak van de instroom van daglicht, connectie met de omgeving en toegankelijkheid voor functionele stromen.

  Het ontwerp van VK voorziet in een duidelijke opsplitsing van ambulante en acute patiÃ«nten, met toepassing van het nieuwe ESI triagesysteem (Emergency Severity Index) en ruime wachtzones vooraan de afdeling. Daarnaast wordt de ruimte functioneel opgedeeld in urgentiezones.

  High-care bevindt zich onmiddellijk na triage, en vlakbij de liften die naar het OK voeren. Low-care en medium-care situeren zich aan de andere kant van de spoed, het verst af van de receptie. Deze patiÃ«nten moeten vaak iets langer wachten op behandeling. Vandaar dat deze zone grenst aan de buitengevel, waar veel daglicht binnen stroomt.

  Deze medische ruimtes werden zeer functioneel aangekleed, met roestvrij staal, synthetische wanden, geleidende vloeren en technische plafonds. Wit is de hoofdtoon, met uitzondering van de signaalkleuren op de deuren: rood voor high-care, geel voor medium-care en groen voor low-care . Het personeel gaf aan beter te functioneren in een sobere omgeving, met een minimum aan afleiding.

  In contrast met deze klinische omgeving staan de meer serene wachtzones aan weerszijden van de spoeddienst. Een wachtzone aan de receptie en een wachtzone in low-care werden vormgegeven met warme kleuren en aangename materialen. De verlichting is telkens verwerkt in diepe curves met perforatie, en bakenen de zones af. De wachtzone in low-care kreeg bovendien een gestileerde boom. Deze referentie naar de natuur roept associaties op die moeten bijdragen aan een ontspannen en geborgen sfeer. Daarnaast bevat dit vaste meubel een speelhoek voor kinderen.

  Uiteraard bevat de spoed alle andere noodzakelijke faciliteiten, waaronder boxen voor isolatie, chirurgie, gipsen, pediatrie en allerhande ingrepen en onderzoek. Naast de ingang voor acute patiÃ«nten en centraal tussen alle specifieke zones, bevindt zich de personeelsruimte. Ook deze ruimte geniet maximaal van daglicht.[:]"
        ["post_title"]=>
        string(146) "[:en]Europe Clinics Saint Michael's, emergency unit[:fr]Cliniques de l'Europe Saint-Michel, urgences[:nl]Europaziekenhuizen Sint-Michiel, spoed[:]"
        ["post_excerpt"]=>
        string(135) "[:en]reconditioning emergency services and morgue[:fr]reconditionnement urgences et morgue[:nl]herconditionering spoed en mortuarium[:]"
        ["post_status"]=>
        string(7) "publish"
        ["comment_status"]=>
        string(6) "closed"
        ["ping_status"]=>
        string(6) "closed"
        ["post_password"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["post_name"]=>
        string(39) "europe-clinics-emergency-saint-michaels"
        ["to_ping"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["pinged"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["post_modified"]=>
        string(19) "2015-07-14 07:36:58"
        ["post_modified_gmt"]=>
        string(19) "2015-07-14 07:36:58"
        ["post_content_filtered"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["post_parent"]=>
        int(0)
        ["guid"]=>
        string(64) "http://vkgroup.dx-solutions.be/en/?post_type=project&p=1777"
        ["menu_order"]=>
        int(0)
        ["post_type"]=>
        string(7) "project"
        ["post_mime_type"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["comment_count"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["filter"]=>
        string(3) "raw"
        ["p2p_id"]=>
        string(4) "1386"
        ["p2p_from"]=>
        string(4) "1777"
        ["p2p_to"]=>
        string(4) "2053"
        ["p2p_type"]=>
        string(15) "project_to_post"
      }
    }
  }
```

Then I do : `$json_value = json_encode($array);`.

But when I want to validate the json I get the following error:

```
Parse error on line 218:
...    "post_content": "[:en]Of course sust
-----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

The post_content in my json is equal to:

```
"post_content": "[:en]Of course sustainable design is not a separate discipline. In itself, ecologically aware design is an issue in all disciplines. The architects and engineers at VK Architects & Engineers are therefore also aware of the importance and necessity of this aspect. They also know that they are supported internally in this approach by several experts.\r\n\r\nThe energy concept is based as far as possible on passive measures combined with renewable energy production, with a view to optimal comfort<\/strong> for the user. To minimise the total environmental impact of a project, VK follows the BREEAM philosophy. This specifically accounts for aspects such as water, ecology, materials, health, management etc. The life cycle cost<\/strong> of the project is also analysed to come up with the most efficient solutions. Energy and maintenance costs are central here.\r\n\r\nSustainable and maintenance-conscious design is determined by the concept, choice of materials and components and by long-term operation (maintenance costs), environmental friendliness and efficient energy use.\r\n\r\nVK distinguishes three important pillars here:\r\n
\r\n\t
an ecological pillar: energy, materials, transport, waste, water etc.<\/li>\r\n\t
an economic pillar: profitability, lifespan, flexibility, determining correct dimensions etc.<\/li>\r\n\t
a social pillar: comfort, safety, aesthetics, integration into the surroundings etc.None of these aspects are separate from the others: they are intertwined, making an integrated approach<\/strong> important. Common sense prevails over high-tech applications here.This integrated approach is based on less energy, more comfort and better usability. It also takes the different \u2018life phases\u2019 of the project into account: design, implementation, use and operation, possibly reassignment and demolition. Our experts study various scenarios here with the help of dynamic calculation and simulation software.\r\n\r\nWith this strategy, VK Architects & Engineers puts more energy into the design so that it uses less energy once it is complete.\r\n\r\nVK is an accredited professional for BREEAM and a member of the Brussels Institute of Environmental Management, the Flemish Energy Agency, the Walloon Department of Energy, the Passive House Platform, the Scientific and Technical Centre for the Building Industry, the US Green Building Council and the International Building Performance Simulation Association.<\/li>\r\n<\/ul>[:fr]La durabilit\u00e9 dans les projets ne constitue bien entendu pas une discipline isol\u00e9e. En soi, la conception \u00e9cologique est une question qui touche toutes les disciplines. Les architectes et ing\u00e9nieurs de VK Architects & Engineers sont donc conscients de l\u2019importance et de la n\u00e9cessit\u00e9 de cet aspect. Pour cette approche, ils peuvent compter sur le support interne d\u2019une s\u00e9rie d\u2019experts.\r\n\r\nLe concept d\u2019\u00e9nergie se base autant que possible sur des mesures passives en combinaison avec la g\u00e9n\u00e9ration d\u2019\u00e9nergies renouvelables afin d\u2019offrir un confort optimal<\/strong> \u00e0 l\u2019utilisateur. Pour minimiser la charge totale d\u2019un projet sur l\u2019environnement, VK applique la philosophie BREEAM. Celle-ci prend en compte de mani\u00e8re sp\u00e9cifique des aspects tels que l\u2019eau, l\u2019\u00e9cologie, les mat\u00e9riaux, la sant\u00e9, le management\u2026 Le co\u00fbt du cycle de vie<\/strong> du projet est analys\u00e9 lui aussi afin de pr\u00e9voir les solutions les plus efficientes. Les co\u00fbts d\u2019\u00e9nergie et les frais d\u2019entretien occupent de ce pont de vue une place centrale.\r\n\r\nLa conception durable et \u00e0 faible entretien est d\u00e9termin\u00e9e tant par le concept, le choix des mat\u00e9riaux et des composants que par l\u2019exploitation \u00e0 long terme (frais d\u2019entretien), l\u2019\u00e9cologie et l\u2019utilisation rationnelle de l\u2019\u00e9nergie.\r\n\r\nVK distingue ici trois piliers importants :\r\n
\r\n\t
un pilier \u00e9cologique : \u00e9nergie, mat\u00e9riaux, transport, d\u00e9chets, eau\u2026<\/li>\r\n\t
un pilier \u00e9conomique : rentabilit\u00e9, dur\u00e9e de vie, flexibilit\u00e9, dimensionnement correct\u2026<\/li>\r\n\t
un pilier social : confort, s\u00e9curit\u00e9, esth\u00e9tique, int\u00e9gration dans le cadre\u2026Tous ces aspects ne sont pas ind\u00e9pendants, mais sont \u00e9troitement li\u00e9s entre eux : une approche int\u00e9gr\u00e9e<\/strong> est donc vitale. Et le bon sens y prime sur les applications high-tech sophistiqu\u00e9es.\r\n\r\nLes points de d\u00e9part de cette approche int\u00e9gr\u00e9e sont : moins d\u2019\u00e9nergie, plus de confort, meilleure utilit\u00e9. Elle tient compte \u00e9galement des diff\u00e9rentes \u00ab phases de vie \u00bb du projet : conception, ex\u00e9cution, utilisation et exploitation, r\u00e9affectation \u00e9ventuelle et d\u00e9molition. Pour ce faire, nos experts envisagent diff\u00e9rents sc\u00e9narios \u00e0 l\u2019aide de logiciels dynamiques de calcul et de simulation.\r\n\r\nAvec cette strat\u00e9gie, VK Architects & Engineers consacre plus d\u2019\u00e9nergie au concept, de sorte que la r\u00e9alisation consomme moins d\u2019\u00e9nergie apr\u00e8s.\r\n\r\nVK est un professionnel accr\u00e9dit\u00e9 pour BREEAM et membre de l\u2019Institut Bruxellois de Gestion de l\u2019Environnement, du Vlaams Energie-Agentschap, du D\u00e9partement de l\u2019Energie wallon, de la Plate-forme Maison Passive, du Centre Scientifique et Technique de la Construction, de l\u2019US Green Building Council et de l\u2019International Building Performance Simulation Association.<\/li>\r\n<\/ul>[:nl]Duurzaamheid in ontwerpen is uiteraard geen losstaande discipline. In se is ecologisch bewust ontwerpen een zaak voor en van alle disciplines. De architecten en ingenieurs van VK Architects & Engineers zijn zich dan ook bewust van het belang en de noodzaak van dit aspect. Daarbij weten zij zich voor deze benadering intern ondersteund door een aantal experts.\r\n\r\nHet energieconcept baseert zich zoveel mogelijk op passieve maatregelen in combinatie met hernieuwbare energieproductie, met het oog op een optimaal comfort<\/strong> voor de gebruiker. Om de totale milieubelasting van een project te minimaliseren volgt VK de BREEAM-filosofie. Daarbij worden aspecten zoals water, ecologie, materialen, gezondheid, management \u2026 specifiek in rekening gebracht. Ook wordt de levenscycluskost<\/strong> van het project geanalyseerd om de meest effici\u00ebnte oplossingen te voorzien. Hier staan energiekost en onderhoudskost centraal.\r\n\r\nDuurzaam en onderhoudsbewust ontwerpen wordt zowel door het concept, de keuze van materialen en componenten bepaald, als door de exploitatie op lange termijn (onderhoudskosten), de milieuvriendelijkheid en het effici\u00ebnt energiegebruik.\r\n\r\nVK onderscheidt hierbij drie belangrijke pijlers:\r\n
\r\n\t
een ecologische pijler: energie, materialen, transport, afval, water \u2026<\/li>\r\n\t
een economische pijler: rentabiliteit, levensduur, flexibiliteit, correcte dimensionering \u2026<\/li>\r\n\t
een sociale pijler: comfort, veiligheid, esthetiek, integratie in de omgeving \u2026Al deze aspecten staan niet op zich maar zijn nauw met elkaar verweven: een ge\u00efntegreerde aanpak<\/strong> is dan ook belangrijk. Daarbij primeert het gezond verstand op gesofisticeerde high-tech toepassingen.Deze ge\u00efntegreerde aanpak gaat uit van minder energie, meer comfort, een betere bruikbaarheid. Het houdt ook rekening met de verschillende \u2018levensfasen\u2019 van het project: ontwerp, uitvoering, gebruik en exploitatie, eventueel herbestemming en afbraak. Daarbij bestuderen onze experts verschillende scenario\u2019s met behulp van dynamische reken- en simulatiesoftware.\r\n\r\nMet deze strategie stopt VK Architects & Engineers meer energie in het ontwerp zodat nadien de realisatie minder energie verbruikt.\r\n\r\nVK is een geaccrediteerd professional voor BREEAM, en lid van het Brussels Instituut voor Milieubeheer, het Vlaams Energie-Agentschap, het Waalse departement voor Energie, het Passiefhuis Platform, het Wetenschappelijk en Technisch Centrum voor het Bouwbedrijf, de US Green Building Council en de International Building Performance Simulation Association.<\/li>\r\n<\/ul>[:]",
```

Do I have to escape the post_content separately? And if so, how can I do this?

Comment: how are you generating the posts?

Comment: @nielsv You might try using [`wp_json_encode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_json_encode/). It will convert strings to the proper encoding for serialization. If that doesn't work, it might be an error in the parser you are using and not a problem with the data that is being encoded.

Answer (score 1):

Newlines are not valid inside json strings. However you are outputting this code or otherwise checking it for sanity is somehow adding newlines into your long strings here.

Check that your strings really are all one line and not broken up into multiple lines.